# How to add multiple python-path in apache default conf file

Tags: python, django, apache

I want to add multiple entries for python-path in the 000-default.conf apache configuration file.

```
WSGIDaemonProcess my_project python-path=/home/user/Documents/my_project python-home=/home/user/Documents/my_project/virtualenv
```

In the above line, python-path variable contains the path to my django project root directory, I want to specify some other directory path so that I can import those modules from my django project app files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When specifying the PYTHONPATH env variable, multiple paths are separated by ":", you could try the same here, i.e. `python-path=/some/dir:/some/other/dir`.

Comment: Damn, I was trying with ; or , 

Thanks Man.